# Wanting to merge rows with same ID in large select query

Tags: sql, group-by, sql-server-2014

I've got a big select query, nearly 50 fields, across a few tables. Part of it is to check whether a user is an learner, admin, etc. As you can see below it is returning multiple lines. Now I want to aggregate them down into one line, basically an or operation.

Edit 1: Each of the bool values are derived using a case statement from a single field

```
User ID | Learner | Admin | Facilitator | Advisor
1   0   0   0   1
1   0   1   0   0
2   0   0   1   0
3   0   0   1   0
3   0   1   0   0
```

To this

```
User ID | Learner | Admin | Facilitator | Advisor
    1   0   1   0   1
    2   0   0   1   0
    3   0   1   1   0
```

Adding GROUP BY UserID gives an error

`Column 'Users.FirstName' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.`

I probably could wrap MAX around each field but it would not be a pretty query and I figure that there must be a better way to do this

This is in MS SQL 2014

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure you're going to find a cleaner query than using MAX() and GROUP BY.

Comment: Why not show your raw table (the one with the single field you're using CASE on)?

Comment: If you need help with a SQL statement, it helps if you post the actual SQL statement.

Answer (score 1):

you can do a join between the aggregate query and the table "Users", like this:

```
SELECT users.userid
    ,users.firstName
    ,tMax.learner
    ,tMax.admin
    ,tMax.facilitator
    ,tMax.advisor
FROM users 
inner JOIN (select userid,
            max(learner) as learner, max(admin) as admin,
            max(facilitator) as facilitator, max(advisor) as advisor
        from t
        group by userid) AS tMax ON tmax.userId = users.userId
```

Comment: That's an unnecessary complication.

Comment: Maybe in this example, but if the select contains many fields, isolating the aggregations avoids repeating all in the group by.

Comment: This probably could reduce _complications_ if subquery had moved to CTE.

Comment: The OP's problem is that he's trying to group records without using an aggregate function.  He said he doesn't want to use MAX.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using aggregation:

```
select userid,
       max(learner) as learner, max(admin) as admin,
       max(facilitator) as facilitator, max(advisor) as advisor
from t
group by userid;
```

EDIT:

SQL Server doesn't have *bool* as a data type.  If you mean `bit`, then you can use conditional logic:

```
select userid,
       max(cast(learner as int)) as learner, max(cast(admin as int)) as admin,
       max(cast(facilitator as int)) as facilitator, max(cast(advisor as int)) as advisor
from t
group by userid;
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me, same error as mentioned above

FWIW each of the bool values are calculated using case statements off a single field